# Append class with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just created a variable for a specific site of mine but I want to append a class entitled "partner-text" if I'm actually on that site. If I'm on a different site then don't append it. How can I do that?

```
use(function() {
var inPartnerPath = currentPage.getPath().indexOf("partners_Skate_Daily");
// to check if the site is under partners_Skate_Daily folder if yes then it should return true

var isPartner = (inPartnerPath != -1) ? 'true' : 'false';

return {
    isPartner: isPartner
};

});
```

Comment: you should use the actual bool values when checking, not 'true' but true etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'true'` and `'false'` are strings.  You want to use the *boolean* values `true`/`false`.

You don't even need the `?:` here, `!=` *already* returns you a boolean.

```
var isPartner = inPartnerPath != -1;
```

Comment: but how do I append "partner-text" if isPartner is true?

Comment: @Code4life: Append the class to *what*?  What element?  We need a little more info here.

Comment: if (isPartner == true) {
  $(".main").find("'[class^=component-]'").addClass(".partner-text");
}                                Does this look right?

Comment: @Code4life: Should be: `.addClass("partner-text")` (no `.`).  P.S. You could just do `if(isPartner)`.